# Java 8 Merge maps in iterator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an iteraror where in every iteration I´m creating a new map

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

Now I would like to merge in every iteration the last emitted map with the new one.

If I send a list of items to `getMap`

```
{"a","a","b"}
```

I expect to receive a map of

```
["a",{"foo:a", "foo:a"}, "b",{"foo:b"}]
```

I try to use reduce function, but because putall only works if I use multimap and not map, is not a good option.

Here my code

```
public Map<String, List<String>> getMap(List<String> items){
       return items().stream()
                .map(item -> getNewMap(item) --> Return a Map<String, List<String>>
                .reduce(new HashMap<>(), (o, p) -> {
                    o.putAll(p);
                    return o;
                });
}

public Map<String, List<String>> getNewMap(String item){
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(item, Arrays.asList("foo:" + item));
    return map;
}
```

I´m looking for a no verbose way to do it.

Comment: Do consider accepting Holger's solution instead of mine, it is a lot cleaner and better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is to flat map each intermediate map to its entries and make a single map out of that.

In the following code, each item is mapped to its corresponding map. Then, each map is flat mapped to its entries and the Stream is collected into a map.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getMap(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "b")));
    // prints "{a=[foo:a, foo:a], b=[foo:b]}"
}

public static Map<String, List<String>> getMap(List<String> items) {
    return items.stream()
                .map(item -> getNewMap(item))
                .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue,
                    (l1, l2) -> { List<String> l = new ArrayList<>(l1); l.addAll(l2); return l; }
                ));
}

public static Map<String, List<String>> getNewMap(String item) {
    Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(item, Arrays.asList("foo:" + item));
    return map;
}
```

In the case of multiple keys, this appends each list together.

Comment: Producing maps just to flatmap them produces impressive code showing off all the features of the stream API, but I think the OP’s initial approach has misguided you to this baroque solution. Starting with zero and using the right tool leads to [a much simpler solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35699445/2711488). And, as a final note, when you really need a single entry `Map`, consider [`singletonMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap-K-V-)…

Comment: @Holger You're correct that for this specific instance, it is possible to do it much simpler. But what if the inner maps are `[foo:..., bar:...]`?

Comment: There is no such possibility given the input and desired output in the question. The existence of an “inner map” is not part of the task but just an artifact of the OP’s first attempt to solve the problem. The initial input is `"a", "a", "b"`, I don’t see how different prefixes could come from there.

Comment: @Holger Hmm re-reading the revisions (the first one being very unclear), I think I answered the Y in the XY problem yes...

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you want to get a `Map<…, List<…>>` from a stream, you should first check, how the [`groupingBy` collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) fits in. In its simplest form, it receives a grouping function which determines the keys of the resulting map and will collect all elements of a group into a list. Since you want the prefix `"foo:"` prepended, you’ll have to [customize this group collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) by inserting a [mapping operation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#mapping-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-) before [collecting the items into a list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--):

```
public static Map<String, List<String>> getMap(List<String> items) {
    return items.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        Collectors.mapping("foo:"::concat, Collectors.toList())));
}
```

The classification function itself is as trivial as the identity function, as you want all equal elements building one group.

Comment: Thanks for the new solution. But about  the concat of the "foo:" + item was just part of the example, actually we´re not doing that in the real code. I´ll take a look to this solution as soon as I can.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether you use `"foo:"::concat` or `x -> "foo:"+x` or whatever mapping function you like. The logic doesn’t change.

Comment: The getNewMap() is just a example method, the real application it´s returning a Map<String, List<String>> with more complex business logic, so the Collectors.mapping(Function) it´s look not possible. But I´ll study your code, and I´ll see if it´s possible to use it. Thanks again.

Comment: Then you possibly over-simplified your question. If the list might have more than one item and you want to merge them, you only have to replace the `toList()` collector of this solution, e.g. to something like `Collector.of(ArrayList::new, List::addAll, (l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;})`. If the map might have multiple items, you’ll need a `flatMap` step before the `collect`, similar to Tunaki’s answer, but that’s still possible without creating an intermediate `Map`. But to get a concrete answer about how to do that, you’ll need a more precise question…